# Equivalent package in JAVA for Python Scikitlearn Preprocessing

Tags: java, python, scikit-learn

Python has this awesome package sklearn.preprocessing which offers pretty useful function to preprocess input data. I was wondering if there is an equivalent for this package in JAVA?

Thanks

Comment: weka has some pretty good preprocessing capabilitites - see the preprocessing tab in the weka explorer http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/